# accuracy of the sub-aggregation from the terms aggregation

Tags: elasticsearch, query-performance, elasticsearch-aggregation

I am having a *daily-stats* record for each mall with fields as follows:

- cpnTotalCount
- orderTotalCount
- orderTime
- mallId
- cpnTotalAmount

There are two fields which I will use `bucket_script` to have a ratio `cpnTotalCount / orderTotalCount` and use `bucket_sort` to get the *topK*.

But if I only select 7 days to get the *topK* malls, I will not get accurate results due to [`doc_count_error_upper_bound`](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-aggregations-bucket-terms-aggregation.html#_calculating_document_count_error)

> Document counts (and the results of **any sub aggregations**) in the terms aggregation are not always accurate. Each shard provides its own view of what the ordered list of terms should be. These views are combined to give a final view.

Is there any other way around to achieve a better balance between "accuracy" and "performance".

Any help will really appreciated ;)

---

```
{
  "size": 10,
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "filter": [
        {
          "range": {
            "orderTime": {
              "from": 1589385600000,
              "to": 1590249599999,
              "include_lower": true,
              "include_upper": true,
              "boost": 1.0
            }
          }
        },
        {
          "range": {
            "cpnTotalCount": {
              "from": 3,
              "to": null,
              "include_lower": true,
              "include_upper": true,
              "boost": 1.0
            }
          }
        }
      ],
      "adjust_pure_negative": true,
      "boost": 1.0
    }
  },
  "aggs": {
    "es_aggs_bucketing": {
      "terms": {
        "field": "mallId",
        "size": 20,
        "shard_size": 10000,
        "min_doc_count": 1,
        "shard_min_doc_count": 0,
        "show_term_doc_count_error": false,
        "order": [
          {
            "_count": "desc"
          },
          {
            "_key": "asc"
          }
        ]
      },
      "aggregations": {
        "es_aggs_count_one": {
          "sum": {
            "field": "cpnTotalCount"
          }
        },
        "es_aggs_count_two": {
          "sum": {
            "field": "orderTotalCount"
          }
        },
        "es_aggs_sum_one": {
          "sum": {
            "field": "cpnTotalAmount"
          }
        },
        "es_aggs_script": {
          "bucket_script": {
            "buckets_path": {
              "orderCount": "es_aggs_count_two",
              "couponCount": "es_aggs_count_one"
            },
            "script": {
              "source": "params.couponCount/params.orderCount",
              "lang": "painless"
            },
            "gap_policy": "skip"
          }
        },
        "sort": {
          "bucket_sort": {
            "sort": [
              {
                "es_aggs_script": {
                  "order": "desc"
                }
              }
            ],
            "from": 0,
            "size": 40,
            "gap_policy": "SKIP"
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If the dataset is not very huge, in my case it could reach `150GB` in a year, so I am trying to

- use `30` shards to hold the mall-level records and
- bind the `mallId` to the `routing` to ensure each mall-level ratio is accurate